# Cannot create TvInputInfo when implementing Android TV Input Service

Tags: android, android-source, android-looper

To create a `TvInputInfo`, we can use the `Builder` in the `TvInputInfo`, which goes to

```
//frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.java
public TvInputInfo build() {
...
hdmiConnectionRelativePosition = getRelativePosition(mContext, mHdmiDeviceInfo);
```

and then

```
private static int getRelativePosition(Context context, HdmiDeviceInfo info) {
    HdmiControlManager hcm = (HdmiControlManager) context.getSystemService(Context.HDMI_CONTROL_SERVICE);
    if (hcm == null) {
        return HdmiUtils.HDMI_RELATIVE_POSITION_UNKNOWN;
    }
    return HdmiUtils.getHdmiAddressRelativePosition(info.getPhysicalAddress(), hcm.getPhysicalAddress());
}
```

The `hcm.getPhysicalAddress()` at the last line goes to

`mService.getPhysicalAddress()` and `mHdmiCecController.getPhysicalAddress()`

Finally, reach

```
//frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/hdmi/HdmiCecController.java
@ServiceThreadOnly
int getPhysicalAddress() {
    assertRunOnServiceThread();
    return mNativeWrapperImpl.nativeGetPhysicalAddress();
}
```

Here, calling `assertRunOnServiceThread()` outside of the `HdmiControlService` throws an exception.

```
private void assertRunOnServiceThread() {
    if (Looper.myLooper() != mControlHandler.getLooper()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should run on service thread.");
    }
```

Is it a known issue?
Or if there exists some other method to create a `TvInputInfo` without reaching the above `assertRunOnServiceThread` statement?

Comment: None of this appears to be your code. Are you doing anything unusual, in terms of threads, where you call `build()`?

Comment: I call build() in one of the TvInputService. The codes are the Android framework.

Comment: Seems been fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269402890?pli=1

Comment: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/2446307